# How to rename a "main" document with several fields and collections (object) in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The question in the title actually already has an answer. You cannot. At least not without a work-around.
The way to "rename" a document would be to get a copy of all of its contents and store it under a new (= renamed) id.

Below is a simplified example for my issue:

[image: Example]

Let's say the documents under the "cars" collection are named according to the license number of the car.  There is a typo in the license number, and now we need to correct it (= rename it).

What is the best and most efficient way to get ALL the contents of e.g. CAR-001 and set them as a new document? There are several data fields directly under the document, as well as several collections with different documents.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulk rename solution, and no shortcuts here.  You will have to apply the solution you already know (copy the document) to each individual document that needs to be changed.

In the future, you may want to consider *not* using a string that someone types as the id of a document.  Let Firestore assign a random ID to the document, and make the typed data a field of that document instead.  You can search using that field.  It's much easier to change a field than a document ID, as you've seen.